# Kotlin - getPendingIntent with multiple flags syntax

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to notify simple notification as in Java code

what is the syntax for this line in kotlin?

```
stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

in kotlin, I can't use **'|'** for 2 flags, only like this:

```
stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
```

Comment: In kotlin you use 'or'

Answer (score 21):

You can find the available bitwise operations in the official docs [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#operations). These are all infix functions that are spelled out in Kotlin instead of using special symbols.

In your case, you can do the following:

```
stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```